# How to start ChromeDriver in headless mode when loading a Chrome Extension

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome-extension, headless-browser

This is the C# code I have. When I run it it starts in headless mode but it seems to have an issue with the Chrome extension.

```
 [Test]
        public async Task Start()
        {
            var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            var option = new ChromeOptions();


            option.AddExtension(MainPageElements.extensionPath);
            option.AddArguments("headless");
            using (var browser = new ChromeDriver(option))
            {
                WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, option);
                webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                //more code
            }
         }
```

This is the error I get when I run it:

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background.html

The extension is MetaMask. It's a crypto wallet.

It could be not possible at all using headless mode when loading this Chrome extension since it opens a new pop up window of its own...

edit: Version of ChromeDriver - 108.0.5359.7100

Comment: version of chromedriver? try with `option.AddArguments(--headless=chrome)` and if it doesn't work with  `option.AddArguments(--headless=new)`. Source https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36

Comment: Version of ChromeDriver - 108.0.5359.7100. But when I try option.AddArguments(--headless=chrome) or option.AddArguments(--headless=new), it underlines it and says "the name 'headless' doesn't exists in the current context". I tried option.AddArguments("--headless=new"), but it seems it needs to be without "", right? What do I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the `"`, you have to put them `option.AddArguments("--headless=chrome")`

Comment: Thank you, I made it work. But option.AddArguments("--headless=new") needs to be before  option.AddExtension(MainPageElements.extensionPath);

Comment: In my code I have a Timer that looks like that: 
     await startTimer(webDriver);
            }

            public async Task startTimer(WebDriver webDriver)
            {
                var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

                while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
                {
                    await Task.Delay(9000);
                    //more code
                 }
When the program reaches 'await startTimer(webDriver);' it stops and stays there. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Does it stay there for more than 9 seconds? Anyway, it would be better if you ask a new question with all the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put

```
option.AddArguments("--headless=new")
```

just before the command `option.AddExtension(MainPageElements.extensionPath);`

source https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c36